# Injecting dependency to existing scripts;

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, dependency-injection

I have a scene with various management scripts many of those point to TimeScaleManager (TSM) which manages the app speed, pause, stop and so on;

What would be the best way inject the TSM (or its interface) to the scripts while the managers already exist from start (no constructor)?

I've tried:

```
private TimeScaleManagement PauseManager; *TimeScaleManagement  is the interface
void Awake(){
    PauseManager = FindObjectsOfType<MonoBehaviour>().OfType<TimeScaleManagement>().ToArray()[0];
}
```

and then using PauseManager.
Can you advise on alternative Method that uses dependency-injection to existing objcets?

Comment: Why not `FindObjectOfType<TimeScaleManagement>()` ?

Comment: Its a great way to find an Object.
Interface is not an object and cannot be found with FindObjectOfType directly

Answer (score 2):

You're saying the managers exist from the start, as if to mean that "the scripts" do not. If that's the case then you should have whatever is instantiating those scripts be responsible for injecting it.

The easiest way for determining how/if the scripts need to be injected would be to create an interface that accepts the TimeScaleManagement, then anything that needs it implements the interface and you can go from there. Something like

```
public interface INeedTimeScaleManagement
{
    void SetTSM(TimeScaleManagement tsm);
}
```

then when you instantiate your prefab (which I'm assuming is how the scripts get introduced later) you could do

```
var instance = GameObject.Instantiate //...
var needsTsms = instance.GetComponentsInChildren<INeedTimeScaleManagement>();
foreach(var needsTsm in needsTsms)
{
    needsTsm.SetTSM(yourTsmReference);
}
```